# How create custom text(glyph) animation by Qt

Tags: qt, animation, qgraphicsview, glyph, qgraphicstextitem

I want to make a dynamic text animation with Qt for arabic and persian texts?can you help me?
You can see an example of what i need.

Trust sample
[image]

wrong sample
[image]

Comment: I can make an animation but in arabic and persian texts the letters are separated.some programmer suggested me to use glyph but I dont know how I should do that

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use the following classes: `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView` to handle and display your graphics, `QGraphicsTextItem` to display each character, `QGraphicsItemAnimation` to animate characters.

I do not know how exactly acts the example you've posted and which transformations are applied. I wrote a simple example. Here the initial rotation and translation of each item is set randomly, and the final positions are without any transformation.

```
QString text = "test";
int current_width = 0;
QFont font("", 30);
QTimeLine *timeline = new QTimeLine(2000);
foreach(QChar c, text) {
  QGraphicsTextItem* item = scene.addText(c);
  item->setFont(font);
  item->adjustSize();
  item->setPos(current_width, 0);
  current_width += item->textWidth();
  QGraphicsItemAnimation *animation = new QGraphicsItemAnimation;
  animation->setItem(item);
  animation->setTimeLine(timeline);
  animation->setRotationAt(0, 360.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX);
  animation->setTranslationAt(0, 100 * rand() / RAND_MAX,
                                 100 * rand() / RAND_MAX);
  animation->setRotationAt(1, 0);
  animation->setTranslationAt(1, 0, 0);
}
ui.graphicsView->setScene(&scene);
timeline->start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution but it is not practical for arabic and persian texts and the letters are seprated

Comment: Can you not overlap the `QGraphicTextItem`s?